# How to create HMAC-SHA-256 signature using apex

Tags: apex

I am using the below code to get the HMAC SHA 256. But signature debug is not getting printed.

```
public void genrateSignature() {
    String salt = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
    String secretKey = 'xjoavU2LaJ1vaGCx4Ekd';

    String signature = generateHmacSHA256Signature(salt, secretKey);

    System.debug('Signature : '+signature);
}

private static String generateHmacSHA256Signature(String saltValue, String secretKeyValue) {
    String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA256';

        Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(saltValue), Blob.valueOf(secretKeyValue));

        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
    }
```

Comment: What is your debug log level for the ApexCode category? If it's lower than 'DEBUG' (so, INFO, WARN, ERROR, or NONE), then the 2-argument debug method won't be captured in the log.

Comment: I don't see `generateHmacSHA256Signature(salt, secretKey)` in the Crypto class. Where does that method come from?

Comment: Yes, it is 'DEBUG'.

Comment: It is present in the first method generateHmacSHA256Signature(salt, secretKey).

Answer (score 1):

As Derek pointed out, this must be your debug level. Your code is fine.

Here, I just copy-pasted this out of my DE (this compiles):

```
global class HMAC {

    public static void generateSignature() {
        String salt = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
        String secretKey = 'xjoavU2LaJ1vaGCx4Ekd';
        String signature = generateHmacSHA256Signature(salt, secretKey);
        System.debug('Signature : ' + signature);
    }

    private static String generateHmacSHA256Signature(String saltValue, String secretKeyValue) {
        String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA256';
        Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(saltValue), Blob.valueOf(secretKeyValue));
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
    }
}
```

... run this in execute anonymous:

```
HMAC.generateSignature();
```

And observe your signature hits the debug log.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago, I created this article on my blog (https://eltoroit.herokuapp.com/Blog.app?page=CryptoCode) which shows all the different ways to encrypt/decrypt in Apex.

```
public class CryptoSample {
    public void Demo(){
        Blob bKey;
        String encryptedData;
        String decryptedData;
        String initialData = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

        // Working with keys...
        // Generate key ...
        bKey = GenerateAESKey(256);             
        System.debug('BKey: ' + bKey);
        // but need the String version to save it...
        String sKey = KeyToString(bKey);        
        System.debug('SKey: ' + sKey);
        // and the Blob version to use it...
        Blob b2 = keyFromString(sKey);
        //  OK, but make sure they are the same!
        System.assert(sKey == KeyToString(b2)); 

        // AES128
        bKey = GenerateAESKey(128);
        encryptedData = Encrypt('AES128', bKey, initialData);
        decryptedData = Decrypt('AES128', bKey, encryptedData);
        System.assertEquals(initialData, decryptedData);

        // AES192
        bKey = GenerateAESKey(192); 
        encryptedData = Encrypt('AES192', bKey, initialData);
        decryptedData = Decrypt('AES192', bKey, encryptedData);
        System.assertEquals(initialData, decryptedData);

        // AES256
        bKey = GenerateAESKey(256); 
        encryptedData = Encrypt('AES256', bKey, initialData);
        decryptedData = Decrypt('AES256', bKey, encryptedData);
        System.assertEquals(initialData, decryptedData);
    }

    private String Encrypt(String method, Blob bKey, String data) {
        System.debug('Encrypting: ' + Data);
        Blob bData = Blob.valueOf(data);
        Blob bEncrypted = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV(method, bKey, bData);
        String output = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bEncrypted);
        System.debug('Encrypted: ' + output);
        return output;
    }
    private String Decrypt(String method, Blob bKey, String secureData) {
        System.debug('Decrypting: ' + secureData);
        Blob bSecureData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(secureData);
        Blob bData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV(method, bKey, bSecureData);
        String output = bData.toString();
        System.debug('Decrypted: ' + output);
        return output;
    }

    private Blob GenerateAESKey(Integer Size) {
        // Size values are 128, 192, 256
        return Crypto.generateAesKey(Size);
    }
    private String keyToString(Blob bKey) {
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bKey);
    }
    private Blob keyFromString(String sKey) {
        return EncodingUtil.base64Decode(sKey);
    }
}
```

As mentioned by others, I think your code seems fine.