# How to create RS256 signature using apex

Tags: apex, crypto

I read the Question from here: [How to create HMAC-SHA-256 signature using apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127442)

I need the same thing but I would like to use the RS256 algorithm.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried just changing the algorithm name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:**  I'm not a crypto expert, this is an informed guess using the linked references.

According to [the Wikipedia article on JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token),

> Typical cryptographic algorithms used [for signatures] are HMAC with SHA-256 (HS256) and RSA signature with SHA-256 (RS256)

Sp "HS256" refers to an HMAC, which [Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) as a "Hash-based message authentication code", where as "RS256" is an "RSA Signature" (not an HMAC), but both are computed using the same hash type (SHA-256).

The answer you link to generated the signature using `Crypto.generateMAC()` as follows:

```
String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA256';
Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(saltValue), Blob.valueOf(secretKeyValue));
```

According to the [documentation for Crypto.generateMAC()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_generateMac).

> The valid values for algorithmName are:
>
> - hmacMD5
> - hmacSHA1
> - hmacSHA256
> - hmacSHA512

So no "RS256" in the list, but the method is named `CreateMAC()`, and from the above we believe the RS256 is a signature, not an HMAC.  Looking at the Crypto library we see:

> `sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey)`
>
> Computes a unique digital signature for the input string, using the specified algorithm and the supplied private key.

Further, `RSA-SHA256` is a valid value for `algorithmName`.  So I suspect that you need something like:

```
string input="...";  // what you want to sign
string privateKey="...";  // your private key
blob rs256sig = Crypto.sign(
    'RSA-SHA256', 
    Blob.valueOf(input), 
    Blob.valueOf(privateKey));
```

**Update:** Note that `Crypto.sign()` returns a `blob`, which is binary data.  If you need the signature in a text format, you can encode it as Base64 or Hex using [`EncodingUtil`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_classes_restful_encodingutil).  I believe that hex encoding is common for signatures, e.g.,

```
string hexSignature = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(rs256sig);
```

Comment: it is working , but how can I receive the signature ? When I print the blob in the console it is writting Blob[128] and when I am doing  rs256sig.toString() ,I receive the error System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Comment: @Raphym see Update appended to answer.